# Rails koala getting omniauth user's groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, koala, facebook-group

I want to get a visitor groups. It works just fine when I am connected with my account (the administrator of the app) but when I connect with another account the groups.count == 0

```
def index

if (@current_visitor)
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@current_visitor.oauth_token)
  groups = @graph.get_connections("me", "groups").select 
  puts groups.count
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask user for groups permission.

In case you're using omniauth-facebook, just add :scope => 'user_groups' to your configuration, besides app id and app secret.

Detail of permission with facebook login can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2